# BSD socket not working

Tags: linux, sockets, embedded, system

UPDATE: src updated based on suggestions. strcat a \n\0 onto command and changing sizeof. Client has a "Succeed" on sending, but server never "succeeds" on receiving.

I have put a lot of working into trying to get a regular old TCP socket working. I basically have a simple client and a server setup. Currently I don't receive anything at all on my server, and I only get 4 bytes on my client ("GOTY" in this example).

Server output outputs this and moves on:

```
RECEIVED (null)
```

Client output just blocks and never stops. If I kill the server I get this output

```
Connect success
Received Response:
```

SERVER

```
int Server::update(char *getbuf)
{
    int ready = poll(pollfds, 1, 100);

    if (ready == -1)
    {
        logger.info("Poll failed");
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (pollfds[0].revents & POLLIN)
    {    
        ssize_t z;

        logger.info("Connection available");

        struct sockaddr_in client_address;
        memset(&client_address, 0, sizeof client_address);
        socklen_t alen = sizeof(client_address);

        // ACCEPT
        clientsocket = accept(serversocket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &alen);
        if(!clientsocket)
            logger.fail("Accept Fail");

        // READ
        z = recv(clientsocket, getbuf, 512, MSG_WAITALL);
        if (z < 0)
            fprintf(stderr,"receive failure\n");
        else
            fprintf(stderr,"receive succeed\n");

        getbuf[z] = 0;

        respond(getbuf);

        //closeConnection();

        logger.data("RECEIVED %s", getbuf);

        getbuf[z] = 0;

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

void Server::respond(char *response)
{
    // SEND
    ssize_t z;

    z = send(clientsocket, response, strlen(response), 0);
    if (z < 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"send failure\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr,"send succeed\n");
}
```

CLIENT

I added the client code.  I now use strlen but it doesn't seem to help things.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int abort = 0;
    int port;
    in_addr_t address;
    char *command;

    ssize_t z;
    int com_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct timeval timeout;

    int opt;
    int val = 0;
    char getbuf[512];

    //Defaults
    address = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    port = 4949;

    //INCLUDED ARGUMENTS FROM CLI
    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "a:p:c:")) > 0) 
    {
        switch(opt)
        {
            case 'a':
                address = inet_addr(optarg);
                break;
            case 'p':
                port = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'c':
                abort = 1;
                command = (char *)optarg;
                break;   
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "-a IPADDRESS -p PORT -c COMMAND\n",argv[0]);
        }
    }

    // Server
    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = address;

    if (server_address.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
        fprintf(stderr, "Server address failed\n");

    if(!abort)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No Command given\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "-a IPADDRESS -p PORT -C COMMAND\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Address %s Port %d Command %s\n", inet_ntoa(server_address.sin_addr), port, command);
    }

    // Create com_socket
    com_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (com_socket == -1)
         fprintf(stderr, "Socket failed\n");

    /*
    // Client
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    memset(&client_address,0,sizeof client_address);
    client_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_address.sin_port = 0;
    client_address.sin_addr.s_addr = ntohl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (client_address.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
        fprintf(stderr, "Client address failed\n");

    // Bind
    z= bind(com_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, sizeof (client_address));
    if ( z == -1 )
        fprintf(stderr,"Binding port\n");
    */

    timeout.tv_sec = 2; /* 2 seconds */ 
    timeout.tv_usec = 0; /* + 0 usec */

    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    // Connect
    //z = connectWithTimeout(com_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, len_inet, &timeout);
    z = connect(com_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    if(z == -1)
    {
        if(errno == EINPROGRESS)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EINPROGRESS non block start\n");
        }

        if(errno == EALREADY)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EALREADY non block subsequent request\n");
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Connect failed\n");
    }
    else 
        fprintf(stderr, "Connect success\n");

    strcat(command, "\n\0");

    // SEND
    z = send(com_socket, command, strlen(command)+2, 0);
    if (z < 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"send failure\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr,"send succeed\n");

    // READ
    z = recv(com_socket, getbuf, 512, MSG_WAITALL);
    if (z < 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"receive failure\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr,"receive succeed\n");

    // Output
    fprintf(stderr, "Received Response: %s\n", getbuf);

    close(com_socket);

    exit(1);
}
```

I just have no idea why this is not working. I've been over it again and again.

It's a embedded Linux system.

Comment: You are not showing the function that actually calls `send()`.  I suggest running your server and client under `strace` to see what data and length it is actually passing to `send()`.

Comment: Did you try first to make your code working on a regular Linux desktop, using the numerous tools (in particular `gcc -Wall -g`, `gdb`, `valgrind`, `strace` ...) that are available?

Answer (score 4):

In the server: this is just plain wrong. strlen() returns the length of the string that was in the buffer *before* the read() /recv().

```
    // READ
    z = recv(clientsocket, getbuf, strlen(getbuf), MSG_WAITALL);
    if (z < 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"receive failure\n");
```

Also: in respond(), strlen() assumes that the response "string" is null-termated. It is not.

```
z = send(clientsocket, response, strlen(response), 0);
```

And the same type of error appears to be present in the client code.

UPDATE: since the OP does not know how to live without string functions, I'll illustrate how this could be done.

```
 ... snipped ...
 // READ
    z = recv(clientsocket, getbuf, 512, MSG_WAITALL);
    if (z < 0) {
        // .... if (errno == EAGAIN) continue;
        fprintf(stderr,"receive failure %d(%s) \n"
             , errno, strerror(errno) );
        break; }

    fprintf(stderr,"receive succeed\n");

    respond(getbuf, z);

    return TRUE;
    }
return FALSE;
}

void respond(char *response, size_t siz)
{
// SEND
size_t done;
ssize_t z;

for (done = 0; done < siz; done += z) { 
    z = send(clientsocket, response+done, siz-done, 0);
    if (z < 0) {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) continue;
        fprintf(stderr,"send failure %d(%s)\n"
           , errno, strerror(errno) );
        break; }
    fprintf(stderr,"send succeed\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: So how am I supposed to know the length of what I am receiving? If I put the size of the buffer, will it just hang until it receives 256 bytes?

Comment: No. It will read as many bytes as are available at that moment. Your program should remember how much data it already has collected, and how much room there is left in the buffer.

Comment: So you are confirming I should put the size of the buffer in this case? Because it appears as if it is still hanging on the receive with a value of 256 (size of buffer).

Comment: It depends. If you have message boundaries (eg command-line: commands ending in '\n'), the reader should accumulate data until it has collected a complete "command") If it is only an echo-server (which it appears to be), the server can echo the bytes once it receives them. (but it has to keep track of the amount received, and should use **exactly that amount** when echoing. FWIW: even write() / send() can send partial data: you should check its return value and act accordingly.

Comment: Well it's a network server that currently just echoes what it receives for debugging purposes. Correct me if I'm wrong but a TCP packet can easily fit what I am sending <256 bytes. So I think the whole thing can be sent in once receive. So you're saying that if I put a \n on it the receive will complete?

Comment: Could be. Maybe not. The network layers are permitted to do what they like. (Nagle ?, fragmentation?) On your loopback device, you'll probably never experience partial read() write()s, but don't assume they don't exist. They do.

Comment: I've tried strcat a "\n\0" onto my command. Still seems to not come through. So far I am just testing "HELLO" so I don't know why it's not finishing the command.

Comment: As I said before: **you cannot use string functions because the buffers are not null terminated**.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7148/discussion-between-nathan-mcdavitt-van-fleet-and-wildplasser)

Comment: not strcat? Or is it because I still use strlen for the command? Because I receive the command from cli so I can user strlen on it after appending \n\0 onto it.

Comment: No need for chat. I've already said it all: **your buffers are not strings, because they are not null terminated**. So: no strlen(), no strcpy() and certainly no strcat().

Comment: Great like every example I've ready that just says send(socket,"hello",6,0); It seems like no one wants to share how this is supposed to be done.

Comment: @NathanMcDavitt-VanFleet - "but a TCP packet can easily fit what I am sending".  You should never think about TCP sockets in terms of packets and packet sizes. TCP is a stream protocol.  IP Fragmentation, TCP segmentation, MTU sizes, window size changes, and other burps in the network can cause a "send" to be broken up into random chunks. You should code your "receive" side as if only 1 byte might be received at a time. Don't assume you'll get all the data you expect in the same recv() call, otherwise, it will lead to unexplained bugs down the road.

Comment: Well at this point I am not non blocking anyway, and even if I wanted to code it the way you suggest no one has shown how that might be. Or how I might actually handle strings or buffers differently.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not actually shared the source of your "respond" function, my psychic powers tell me it looks something like this:

```
void Server::respond(char* str)
{
    send(clientsock, str, sizeof(str), 0);
}
```

As such, "sizeof(str)" is evaluating to 4 because that's the size of a pointer on your machine.  That is consistent with the client receiving "GOTY" (the first 4 bytes of the message you intended to send).

Change it to the following:

```
void Server::respond(char* str)
{
    send(clientsock, str, strlen(str), 0);
}
```

Also, you should never assume that that send and recv will return a value equal to the amount of data you expected to send or receive. Hence, you should loop on non-blocking calls to send/recv until the entire message has been sent or consumed.

Comment: How do you know when the message is complete?

Comment: You don't. Youl have to save the incoming characters in a buffer and wait till a '\n' occurs. (or some other protocol-defined statement terminator)

Answer (score -2):

Send operations on sockets are often buffered so it's possible your respond function is not flushing all that data. Try a flush operation at the end of `respond()` to get the extra data.

It's looks to me like you're seeing blocking behaviour you might want to look into how blocking/non-blocking affects sockets.

Comment: Sockets are not buffered; there is no flush function.

Comment: Ah. I've only used socket libraries (as in python asyncore, luasocket, etc) so I guess they add their own buffers. I always assumed it was done by the os.